# How to link_to ruby code and text in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I have the following ruby code that displays how many comments a blog post has:

```
<%= post.comments.count %> comments
```

If a post has 3 comments, for example, what is rendered in the view is "3 comments". What I would like to do now is make this text a link to the post's show page but I'm not sure how to combine ruby code and text into a link_to. The following code will link the number 3 (assuming a post has 3 comments) to the post's show page.

```
<%= link_to post.comments.count, post %>
```

How can I take this statement and make the entire string "3 comments" a link to the show page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost!

Interpolation is what you want. The ruby goes in the #{ }.

```
<%= link_to "#{post.comments.count} comments", post %>
```